# d3.js number format is not displaying properly on bar

Tags: d3.js, number-formatting

I'm working on a horizontal bar graph and would like to display the values on each bar with a specific format. I've tried to code it in many ways but have been unsuccessful in achieving the results I want. I'm using the following code:

```
data = d3.json('data.json')
.then(data => {data
.forEach(d => {
    d.country = d.country;
  d.population = +d.population * 1000;
});

console.log(data);
render(data);

});

const xValuesNumberFormat = number => d3.format(',.0f')(number);

const xValues = d => d.population;

svg.selectAll('text')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('text')
.attr('class', 'bar-value')
.attr('x', xPos)
.attr('y', yPos)
.text(xValues)
.attr('transform',`translate(5,`+yScale.bandwidth()/1.5+`)`)
        ;



[
{"country":"China","population":1415046},
{"country":"India","population":1354052},
{"country":"United States","population":326767},
{"country":"Indonesia","population":266795},
{"country":"Brazil","population":210868},
{"country":"Pakistan","population":200814},
{"country":"Nigeria","population":195875},
{"country":"Bangladesh","population":166368},
{"country":"Russia","population":143965},
{"country":"Mexico","population":130759}
]


svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('class', 'rect')
//.attr('x', xPos)
.attr('y', yPos)
.attr('width', xPos)
.attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())

.on('mouseover', function (d)
 {tooltip.style('display', null);})

.on('mouseout', function (d)
{tooltip.style('display', 'none');})

.on('mousemove', function (d)
{
var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0] ;
var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 20;
tooltip.attr("transform", "translate("+xPos + "," + yPos +")");
tooltip.select('text').text(d3.format(',.0f')(d.population));
})
;
```

As soon as I try to format it I get Nan, undefined and various other errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVtBG.png)

As you can see from the image, I want the number next to the bar to be formatted like the number on the bar. Basically, I just want comma separators. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are your numbers represented as text in the data perhaps?  Some raw data examples would be helpful, as long as some example code that's failing.

Comment: I've added the data and some extra code. I was able to format the mouseover number value properly. It's the values next to bar that I can't seem to format the same. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the data you are passing to the `text` function is the formatted population value, then the bug is upstream of that.  This suggests your formatting function is not getting a number, but a string, object, `undefined`,'NaN', etc.  Recheck what that function receives as arguments.  The code you posted is a bit out of order and incomplete so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
svg.selectAll('text')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('text')
.attr('class', 'bar-value')
.attr('x', xPos)
.attr('y', yPos)
.text(d => d3.format(',.0f')(+d.population))
.attr('transform', `translate(5,`+yScale.bandwidth()/1.5+`)`);
```

Thank you for taking the time to contribute.